# Git - How to move from fork to original repo

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to move from a fork I created on GitHub to the original repo so I can start pushing stuff there, I have the required permissions.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you have original repo permission then change remote url ```git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+multiple+repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to

- add the original as a remote in your local repo using [`git remote add upstream https://github.com/someuser/somerepo.git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)
- push to that remote instead of your fork using [`git push upstream yourlocalbranch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)